# WebPack 2 nested SCSS

Tags: css, module, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

I can't figure out why my nested `SCSS` code does not work.

**Example of nested SCSS**

```
.line {
  .right {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

**Webpack2 loader**

```
exports.scss = {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoader=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader' ]
}
```

If I write it like this then it works

```
.line.right {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
}
```

*I don't want to extract to another file for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the `&`

```
.line {
  &.right {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha! I totally missed this.!! It's working :D I am so stupid :D

Comment: It happens to everybody :) Glad to help